# AWS Quicksight - How do I group by sum and then average?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I've just started using Quicksight and I can't for the life of me figure this out.

Let's say I have a table that goes like this :

| date | country | color | nb_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-11 | USA | Black | 10 |
| 10-11 | USA | Blue | 5 |
| 10-12 | USA | Blue | 20 |
| 10-11 | UK | Black | 10 |
| 10-12 | UK | Black | 15 |
| 10-11 | UK | Blue | 15 |

What I want is the average daily number of sales by country, preferably in a pieplot :

| country | avg_nb_sales |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 17.5 |
| UK | 20 |

So I need first to group by date, country and sum the ratings and then once this aggregation is done I need the average by country. I thought I should be using avgOver(sum(ratings), country) but I can't get it right.

So how do I achieve that ?

I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5):

I have managed to get the result expected though not sure that it is the best way to do it (especially if you have some dates when you get sales only for one country):

```
avgOver(sum(sales), [country])/distinct_count(date)
```

[image]